# XSLT 3.0 Streaming (Saxon) : processing multiple xml files in a folder using saxon:while is throwing error

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I have multiple xml files in a folder, the number of files in the folder is going to be passed to xslt during runtime along with filename and path, when I am trying to process each file using saxon:while i am  getting null pointer exception, I tried without while loop with single file and code worked.

I am sharing simplified version of xml and xslt to show issue iam facing. Iam using Saxon 11.2 EE

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:f="http://www.test.com/function" version="3.0" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" extension-element-prefixes="saxon" >
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
<xsl:mode streamable="yes" on-no-match="shallow-skip" />
<xsl:param name="inputPath"/>
<xsl:param name="filename"/>
<xsl:param name="numberOfFiles"/>
<xsl:variable name="fileCount" select="0" saxon:assignable="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="fullFileName" select="''" saxon:assignable="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Input">
<saxon:while test="$numberOfFiles &gt; $fileCount">
<saxon:assign  name="fullFileName" select="concat($inputPath,$filename,'_',$fileCount,'.xml')"/>
<out><xsl:value-of select="$fullFileName"/></out>
<xsl:apply-templates select="doc($fullFileName)/Input/InData/InfoArray/copy-of(.)" mode="s" />
<saxon:assign name="fileCount" select="$fileCount+1"/>
</saxon:while>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="Info/UnitSellPrice" mode="s">
<price><xsl:value-of select="."/></price>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
<InData>
<InfoArray>
<Info>
<UnitSellPrice>100</UnitSellPrice>
</Info>
<Info>
<UnitSellPrice>324.19</UnitSellPrice>
</InfoArray>
</InData>
</Input>
```

XML 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Input>
<InData>
<InfoArray>
<Info>
<UnitSellPrice>500</UnitSellPrice>
</Info>
<Info>
<UnitSellPrice>200</UnitSellPrice>
</InfoArray>
</InData>
</Input>
```

error:

```
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}concat#5
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}doc#1
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}copy-of#1
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}concat#5
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}doc#1
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
Looking for function Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions}copy-of#1
Trying net.sf.saxon.functions.registry.XSLT30FunctionSet
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2720.invoke(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
com.saxonica.ee.stream.Streamability.getItemType(Streamability.java:267)
```

Comment: How are you using/calling Saxon exactly? From the command line? Please show the exact command line options and parameter settings. If you use Java code please show the relevant code.

Comment: it is getting called from Java code, but  I will try your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would strongly encourage you to avoid using `saxon:assign` and `saxon:while`. These extensions were added to the product very early in its life and they really aren't needed now that XSLT has constructs like tunnel parameters, `xsl:for-each-group` and `xsl:iterate`. You could for example write:

```
<xsl:template match="Input">
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to $fileCount">
     <xsl:variable name="fullFileName"
         select="concat($inputPath,$filename,'_',.,'.xml')"/>
     <out>{$fullFileName}</out>
     <xsl:apply-templates
         select="doc($fullFileName)/Input/InData/InfoArray/copy-of(.)" 
         mode="s" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't actually know whether this has any bearing on the problem, but I'm pretty sure that no-one has tested whether these extensions work in a streamable stylesheet - from the limited stacktrace supplied, it seems to have failed during the streamability analysis, and this might well mean that the streamability analysis for `saxon:assign` and `saxon:while` is defective. If that's the case and we fixed it, we would almost certainly decide that the instruction isn't streamable.

Looking at your code more carefully, it's not clear how you are trying to use streaming. You've got a template rule that matches `Input` elements in streaming mode, but it doesn't actually seem to make use of any data within the `Input` element; while the secondary input files (accessed using `doc()`) are processed without streaming.

Comment: the xslt i posted is not complete one I simplified it to show just issue Iam facing, there are more elements inside Input, my intention is to use streaming in primary and secondary input files if possible,  may be secondary files access I need to change to make streamable using xsl:source-document streamable="yes". I am kind of new to xslt and your suggestions are helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Without relying on extensions, I would think you want e.g. `<xsl:param name="input-uris" as="xs:string*" select="'file1.xml', 'file2.xml', 'file3.xml'"/>` and then start with the initial template (option `-it` on the command line, no `-s` option; from s9api using `callTemplate(null,..)`) using e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each select="$input-uris">
    <xsl:source-document href="{.}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Input/InData/InfoArray/copy-of(.)" mode="s"/>
    </xsl:source-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```